# Is this equation neither concave nor convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Is this equation neither concave nor convex? This is so simple. I think I am just way over thinking it. It's about convex optimization.

When I solve it with the second derivative it's positive. When I plug it back in it's positive too. 
But then with the convex theorem (the whole $f(λx+(1−λ)y)≥λf(x)+(1−λ)f(y)$ stuff) does that mean it's concave because $713/243 > 2/4$?
I am so confused.

Comment: 1) It's hard to understand what the problem is you are facing. Do you need to find extreme values, or test/check for concave/convex? 2) Check $x=\frac{2}{9}$ again, I get a different value for the *extreme* value (maybe that is not what you calculated, but you didn't tell what you calculated). 3) With convexedness, you never compare the function value $\frac{713}{243}$ with the argument $\frac{2}{9}$. Look at the formula you gave again.

Comment: I need to check whether it's concave or convex.  To be honest, I can't really tell what the formula means. I thought that's what it meant. :/ Could you please explain the formula?

Answer (score 2):

It is neither convex nor concave.

The second derivative is $f''(x)=18x-4$, which is negative for $x \lt \frac29\approx 0.222$ and positive for $x \gt \frac29$

Part of it looks like

[image]

Comment: Do you think you could show me why it is neither concave nor convex?
Not using a graph?

Comment: @BiggieSmallz1925 try the second derivative changing sign, as in my answer.  "A twice differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if its second derivative is non-negative there"

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense for it being convex. I get that 2/9 is positive so it it convex. But why is it neither in this case? And sorry for all the trouble. Is it something to do with the first derivative?

Comment: $x=\frac{2}{9}$ (marked in red on my chart) gives a point of inflection where $f''(x)$ changes sign and where $f(x)$ changes from concave to convex.

Comment: Thank you! I got it!
So in finding whether it's concave or convex in a polynomial function, you find the second derivative, set it equal to 0, if it's negative it's concave, and that's it? Do you do the first derivative to check to see the absolute extrema to see tell if it's that way the whole way?

Comment: You should delete the "set it equal to 0"

Comment: But the rest is right? And thank  yo so much! I truly appreciate it. More help than my professor has been so far.